# Does mod satisfy this triangle inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory

I know that it is true that 
$(a+b) \mod \ c=a \ mod \ c+ b \ mod \ c.$

I would like to know: 
Is it true that $|a| \ mod \ c \le |a+b| \mod \ c + |b| \mod \ c$

Comment: It is false, in general, that $(a+b)\bmod c=a\bmod c+b\bmod c$ to begin with. Indeed, for $c=2$ and $a=b=1$, the left-hand side is $0$, whereas the right-hand side is $2$. What is true is that $(a+b)\bmod c=(a\bmod c+b\bmod c)\bmod c$.

Comment: @BaoLing See [e.g. here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1996631/242) for a proof of the identity in the prior comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $a = 2$, $c = 3$, and $b = 1$. Then $|a| \mod c \equiv 2$, but $|a + b| + |b| \equiv 0 + 1 \equiv 1 \mod c$.