# Prove $((u \mod N) \cdot (v \mod N) ) \mod N=(u \cdot v) \mod N?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider $u$ and $v$ are integers. The $\cdot$ is the usual multiplcation.

It seems that 
$$((u \mod N) \cdot (v \mod N) )\overset{?}{=}(u \cdot v) \mod N,$$
is not always true.
For example, on the LHS,
$$((2 \mod 6) \cdot (3 \mod 6) )=6 $$
on the RHS
$$(2 \cdot 3) \mod 6=0,$$
so they are no equal.

> Can we prove that
>   $$((u \mod N) \cdot (v \mod N) ) \mod N=(u \cdot v) \mod N?$$

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996607/prove-that-xy-text-mod-n-x-text-mod-ny-text-mod-n-text

Comment: Wait if u is 2 and v is 3, then u mod 6 = 2 and v mod 6 is 3 which implies that 2*3 mod 6 = 0, which is the same as (v mod 6)*(u mod 6) mod 6. So your counter example is not contrary.

Comment: Um... $6\equiv 0 \mod 6$ so they are "equal".

Comment: Mod is not the remainder operation.  And it it no suprise that for the remainder operation (%) that if a%n=c and b%n=d and c*d > n, that we get (a%n)(b%)!=(ab)%n.  But clearly [(a%n)(b%n)]%n=(ab)%n.  But again, mod is NOT the remainder operation.  It is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

$\mod n $ is not the remainder operator nor any operation.  $a\mod n $ is not a number and it is incorrect to say $14 \mod 8=6$.

It is an equivalent relationship.  The correct statements, all of the following $6\equiv 14 (\mod 8)$ and $14\equiv 6(\mod 8) $ and $14\equiv 22(\mod 8) $ aren't numbers.  They are statements that the numbers $6,14$ and $22$ are *eqivalent* when it comes to arithmetic modulo $8$.  That is $6,14,22$ all have the same remainder.  We don't care about *finding* the remainder. We only care about stating if two numbers are equivalent under this relation.

It's easy to verify/test/prove that if $a\equiv a'(\mod n) $ and $b\equiv b'(\mod n)$ then $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod n$.

In your example $2\times 3=6$ and $6\equiv 0 \pmod 6$ so all is just fine.

That the actual remainder operation isn't distributive is no surprise as the product of remainders can always be larger than the divisor.  That's immaterial.  We don't care about the remainder operator.  And the *remainder* of the products of the remainders *IS* equal to the remainder of the products, anyway.